# How to recreate the 1980's film/colour effect?

Tags: film, effect

This is a still from the movie "Ran" directed by Akira Kurosawa [image: source]

How do I recreate this exact colour effect using Lightroom or camera raw?

After searching i found VSCOFilm which gives your photos different colour effects but neither were close to mimic the colours in the movie's still.

Comment: "*this exact effect*" it is rather unclear to me what this effect is you are talking about. Is it the color? The view? Please specify what it is that you like about this image. Also consider asking this question in [video.se]

Comment: Edited the question. I just need the colour effect/filter like in the image. Sorry I'm looking for photos effect only(not video).

Comment: Perhaps showing us a picture you want to edit might help get a more specific answer?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm still not sure what the effect you are looking for. Can you describe what you think it is?

Comment: JoanneC: I want to  the colours, shadows, highlights, etc from the movie still and apply to my raw photos nothing else and i want to recreate this in Lightroom or camera raw. Read the question again. hope you understand.

Comment: You keep saying "like this", but it's unclear exactly what aspect of "this"  you mean. Do you have costuming like that in the film? Imagine we can't see the photo at all — how would you describe the "this"  that you want?

Comment: experiment with https://www.google.com/nikcollection/products/analog-efex-pro/

Answer (score 3):

Some people seem to assume that using a film emulation filter will make every photo they take have the same characteristics as an image they like that was taken using the particular film being emulated. This is not the case any more than using the same film under vastly different lighting conditions to take two different photos would produce the same characteristics for both photos.

Colors, shadows, highlights, etc. are certainly affected by the response curves of the film used to capture a scene. But they are even more affected by the *light* present in the scene.

To recreate the particular look of an image you not only need to replicate the characteristics of the film used, you also need to replicate the characteristics of the light that was captured by the film.

Specifically, if your image is of a scene that has different colors, shadows, highlights, etc. than the scene depicted in your example then you would need to use *different* response curves to get the same result. If you use the same filter/response curves on a scene lit differently than the image above your result will look like what that other scene would have looked like if shot/processed using the film/techniques used for the image above. It won't look like the scene above. That's what color grading is all about: getting scenes shot under different light to look the same. It's kind of the opposite of using different filters to make the same scene look different.

Answer (score 1):

#### Composition

I would break the composition of the image down

- foreground of the mounted rider
- middle ground of the regiment against a treeline
- background of the mountains.

#### Color

The color scheme is a good example of  (the currently trending) blue-orange hues from the days before digital manipulation (more on blue-orange [here](http://priceonomics.com/why-every-movie-looks-sort-of-orange-and-blue/)).

#### Technique

The time specific appearance I believe comes from two effects both related to the use of film:

1. The foreground and middle ground contain greens which would probably be removed today because that's what people do.
2. The blues in the background reflect the absence of a UV filter and a deliberately exposing the film to produce UV haze across the sky and mountains.

In addition, the framing limits the amount of sky so that UV haze  does not create a strongly washed-out effect to distract a viewers gaze.

#### Unfortunately

Because most digital cameras have a UV Filter built into their internals, recreating the image with a typical digital setup will be hard without post processing to create the UV haze effect via digital manipulation.

#### Fortunately

Getting the greens is as easy as pointing the camera at green foliage and getting the oranges just a matter of selecting an appropriately orange subject.

#### More Unfortunately

The composition masterfully uses diagonals and broken lines to achieve  an artistic vision and few people have the time and will to work out all those details.